# Can a movie "picture a question"?

Tags: word-usage

Here is my sentence:

> This is a wonderful movie sharply picturing the challenges and questions many children face during their childhood.

Is this correct? I know a photo can "picture something" but what about a movie?

The context: The movie approaches questions about sexuality and identity.

Comment: You might want to use the word "portrays" or "depicts" instead.

Comment: Hi Jenny. Thanks for contributing to ELL, it's great to see enthusiastic new users. The reason I put that suggestion in a comment instead of an answer though was because we have a few standards for answers on StackExchange sites. [This guide](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) should give you a clearer idea of what we're looking for and help you to lengthen this into a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"This is a wonderful movie sharply picturing the challenges and questions many children face during their childhood." seems okay, but let me get into the perspective of the question, you want to explain the movie's motive to be " exposing, or making people understand or bringing to light" the "challenges and questions many children face" , so this movie tries to accomplish something other than entertain the audience. It tries to create awareness among the audience, and it tries to have an impact on the society.

When you say it "pictures" it just means the plot of the movie is about "the challenges and questions", I would like to suggest " [puts into perspective](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=put+it+into+perspective) " the issue

"This is a wonderful movie that **puts into perspective** the challenges and questions many children face during their childhood."

I think "puts into perspective" emphasizes to the reader the that the movie has as deeper purpose other than entertainment.

Answer (score 4):

This is a wonderful movie sharply **delineating** the challenges and questions many children face during their childhood.

[Delineate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delineate) means

> to describe, portray, or set forth with accuracy or in detail
>
> *delineate a character in the story*
>
> *delineate the steps to be taken by the government*

You also could use **[illustrating](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/illustrate)**

> to make clear or easily understood by examples, comparisons, etc.; exemplify

While the verb *[picture](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/picture)* can mean to describe or explain, it more often means

> to form a mental picture or impression of; imagine

Comment: Thanks so much Bib, I've already chosen "depicts" but I keep in mind "delineate" and "illustrate". They will for sure, be very useful to me in the near future!